# Trouble resolving padding issue in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: css

I've managed to get this working correctly in IE (annoying), but the solutions I manage to get working cause some odd issues in Chrome and Firefox.  I can't seem to get a set height/padding that works across all the browsers for the handle.

http://plnkr.co/edit/xqYBnz5BHLP844kXJXKs?p=preview

The height of the red, green and gray boxes should all be the same.  Right now they are in IE, but not in Chrome/Firefox.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is arising from several inconsistencies between the attributes of the red/green boxes compared to the gray.

I've been able to make the gray box the same height by changing the following attributes:

```
.stSlide > .stHandle { /* Gray box container */
    padding: 4px 1px;  /* old style:  padding: 1px 1px 3px 0; */
    font-size: 11px;   /* old style:  font-size: 12px; */
    line-height: 18px; /* old style:  line-height: 22px; */
}
```

Comment: Yes!  Thank you, that's a much better solution than what I was working out